# can't set subview's frame in scrollview after scrolling

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, subview

I have an Horizontal-only UIScrollView.
it contains several UIImageViews and a borderView for indicating which one is selected.

borderView is a UIView with border and no content.

**what I want to do：**

when the user tap the imageView, I wish the borderview can move to and overlay on the tapped imageView for indicating.

[image]

**what I did in my code:**

1.Add imageViews with UITapgesture event and borderView to the scrollView

```
-(void)setStaticFilterToBar
{
    _filterList = [APIHelper getStaticFilterList:_originBackgroundImage];
    filterScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,filterScrollView.contentSize.height);
    filterScrollView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor]colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7f];
    int xAis = 64;
    for(int i=0; i<_filterList.count; i++)
    {
        UIImageView *filter = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[_filterList objectAtIndex:i]];
        [filter setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [filter setFrame:CGRectMake(i * xAis,5,60,60)];
        [filter setTag:i];
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self 
action:@selector(filterElementTapToApplyFilter:)];
        [tap setDelegate:self];
        [filter addGestureRecognizer:tap];
        [filterScrollView addSubview:filter];
        if((i+1) * xAis > 320)
        {
            filterScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(filterScrollView.contentSize.width + xAis,
                                               filterScrollView.contentSize.height);
        }
    }

    //add borderview
    UIView *borderView = [[UIView alloc]init];
    borderView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    borderView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
    borderView.layer.cornerRadius = 6;
    [filterScrollView addSubview:borderView];
}

-(void)filterElementTapToApplyFilter:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) recognizer
{
    //apply filter
    [self applyFilterByUIView:recognizer.view];

    //move the borderview to the tapped imageView
    [self selectSubViewsFromScrollView:filterScrollView TargetFrame:recognizer.view.frame];
}
```

2.Tap the imageview to change the borderview's frame value to that of imageView's.
(no matter using `animationwithDuration:animations:completion:` or set the frame directly)

```
-(void)selectSubViewsFromScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView TargetFrame:(CGRect)targetFrame
{
    //borderView is the last subview.
    UIView *borderView = [scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:scrollView.subviews.count-1];

    NSLog(@"Before: borderView.frame:(%d,%d,%d,%d)",(int)borderView.frame.origin.x,
                (int)borderView.frame.origin.y,
                (int)borderView.frame.size.width,
                (int)borderView.frame.size.height);
    //1
    borderView.frame = targetFrame;

    //2 for animation
    //[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    //    borderView.frame = targetFrame;
    //}];
    NSLog(@"After: borderView.frame:(%d,%d,%d,%d)",(int)borderView.frame.origin.x,
                (int)borderView.frame.origin.y,
                (int)borderView.frame.size.width,
                (int)borderView.frame.size.height);
}
```

**The problem I have:**

it works just fine as I predicted for beginning.

But after scrolling the filterScrollView, click on imageview and the borderview won't change its position anymore.but still apply the right filter correctly.

the value of borderview's frame is changed, but the position in screen didn't change.

what happened here? Did I miss anything? Any help would be appreciated.

**Note.** I use storyboard and use No autolayout for all views.

Comment: Why not add a border to the UIImageViews layer instead?

Comment: cause I want the border moving from this imageview to the another with animation. I'm not sure that adding the .layer.boder could have this effect.

Comment: What are the coordinates your providing to make the frameView move after scrolling ? The coordinates should be with respect to the scrollView's content size and not the scrollView's frame

Comment: borderView.frame = selected ImageView's frame.
the scrollView's frame is nerver used.
just updated code for more details.

Answer (score 0):

We can use Collection View ,collection view also internally work same as  scroll view and also we can handle selecting items easily .

in cellforItemAtIndexPath method add selected and normal cells like below

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView        cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {

     UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView     dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"collectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

  if (cell.selected) {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor]; // highlight selection 
   }
   else
  {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; // Default color
   }
 return cell;
 }
```

//once it is selected add the color

```
  -(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath  {

       UICollectionViewCell *datasetCell =[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
       datasetCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor]; // highlight selection
     }
```

//when deselected make it as normal style

```
 -(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

      UICollectionViewCell *datasetCell =[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath]; 
      datasetCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor ClearColor]; // Default color
  }
```